# What is hell for/to one is heaven for/to another - which preposition?

Tags: prepositions

Wanting to indicate that there are things that some people find abhorrent and others savoury, I wrote a sentence

> *What is hell to one is heaven to another*

. After a moment of thought, I changed it to

> *What is hell for one is heaven for another*.

**Which form is the correct one?** Or is there a third, more correct way to put it? [Talk English](http://www.talkenglish.com/grammar/prepositions-of-to-for.aspx) suggest that the former is correct:

> Used to indicate the place, person, or thing that someone or something moves toward, or the direction of something:

But putting both sentences to Grammarly, only the one with "to" is marked as incorrect (it suggest removing the first *to* which is not the best idea).

Answer (score 1):

Both "**for**" and "**to**" can be Googled:

- What is normal for one person is abnormal for another.
- What is natural to one may not be natural to others.

However, I tend to use "**for**" since it implies "*benefits*" whereas "**to**' doesn't and actually works oddly in such context in my opinion.